# How to change the language of a TextBox automatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winforms application in c# and I want a TextBox to change language automatically when it gets focused.

I tried this code:

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetKeyboardLayout(GetInputLanguageByName("fa"));
}
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetKeyboardLayout(GetInputLanguageByName("eng"));
}
public static InputLanguage GetInputLanguageByName(string inputName)
{
    foreach (InputLanguage lang in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages)
    {
        if (lang.Culture.EnglishName.ToLower().StartsWith(inputName))
        {
            return lang;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
private void SetKeyboardLayout(InputLanguage layout)
{
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = layout;
}
```

But when I enter the textBox, the language does not change. What can I do?

Comment: "It didn't work" is not an acceptable way of describing the problem. Please provide more details.

Comment: when i Enter the textBox, language don't change.

Comment: Then say so in your question, so people don't have to read the comments to figure out the problem.

Comment: And maybe the debug steps... did GetInputLanguageByName return a proper value, and the SetKeyboardLayout had no effect, or are you getting a null return there, etc.

Comment: @AmirhosseinParsaeeyan .. have you try my answer ?

Comment: yes @matzone, but didn't work. in condition ' If (Lng.Culture.EnglishName.ToUpper.StartsWith(layout))'  occur an error and say to me that StartsWith(string) and layout is not string. thanks for your help.

Comment: @AmirhosseinParsaeeyan .. that's why I give sample in textbox_enter ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things to check:

1. Is "fa" an installed language?
2. Have you attached textBox1_Enter and textBox1_Leave to events dispatched by textBox1?
3. Have you run it via the debugger and checked GetInputLanguageByName is called and that the correct language is called when focus is gained and lost?

Comment: answer 1 is yes. "fa" is an installed language but i most use "persian"؛ answer of 2 is no, i'm not attached Events but i'm did it now. this did work. i thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ..

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetKeyboardLayout("FA");
}


private void SetKeyboardLayout(InputLanguage layout)
{
foreach (InputLanguage Lng in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages)
{
    if (Lng.Culture.EnglishName.ToUpper().StartsWith(layout.ToString()))
    {
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = Lng;
    }

} 

}
```